# Why the alignment not match

Tags: modeling

hi need help learning with the reference image I have align the side (right hand view) when im trying to align with the left hand view (front view) Mesh getting disturb

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that the reference is from side in orthographic view and from front in perspective. Try to check your model how it looks in perspective. You have to adapt some changes and model it by your guess to make it real, this reference inst good for modeling by exact shape from both views.